# How can I plot the number of occurrences of dates from multiple lists in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm very new to data science, and I've been trying to do this for about 2 weeks and I haven't got any closer to figuring it out.

I have 4 lists of lists with dates (each date represents a sale):

a = [[2012-6], [2013-5], [2014-5]]

b = [[2015-5], [2017-4], [2019-5]]

etc.

I'm trying to plot the number of occurrences of each date across the x axis on a line plot, with each list represented by a different colour line.

I've tried converting them to np arrays, DataFrames, date time objects etc but I have to admit that I'm finally stuck and I'm not getting any closer.

This was the closest I got:

fig_3 = pd.Series(sale1).value_counts().plot.line()

fig_4 = pd.Series(sal2).value_counts().plot.line()

fig_5 = pd.Series(sale3).value_counts().plot.line()

fig_6 = pd.Series(sale4).value_counts().plot.line()

But when I do this it plots them on different plots, and when I can get them on the same plot I can't figure out how to plot the X axis (I tried using xticks, x labels etc).

Other times the dates end up plotting on the Y axis, and I don't know how to switch that either.

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some actual, correctly-formatted data to work with as a [mre], along with an example of the results you want from that data. Format the code and data using the `{}` code formatting button. What should the X and Y axes be? Are you trying to bin the dates and make a type of histogram? Have you tried putting the data into a single dataframe and plotting that? The more information and code you can give us, the better.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a few changes in your code like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                  # <- this row
fig, ax = plt.subplots()                         # <- this row
pd.Series(sale1).value_counts().plot.line(ax=ax) # <- and this parameter to each your line
pd.Series(sale2).value_counts().plot.line(ax=ax)
```